# deployment to IBM worklight 6.2 server

Tags: deployment, websphere, ibm-mobilefirst

I installed an IBM WorkLight Server 6.2 20150129 on a WAS 8.5.5.2 ND on a Windows 2008 DataCenter VM with 4GB ram

min heap:512mb, max heap: 1536mb

I am deploying a *-all.wlapp of around 140mb and following error occurrs.
deploying an app of < 20mb is fine.

server1_exception.log

> com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.throwConfigurationExceptionWithDefaultJavaNS

server1_(very long meaningless text).txt

```
[2/11/15 7:10:54:960 PST]     FFDC Exception:javax.naming.ConfigurationException SourceId:com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.throwConfigurationExceptionWithDefaultJavaNS ProbeId:537 Reporter:java.lang.Class@e712aad3
javax.naming.ConfigurationException: A JNDI operation on a "java:" name cannot be completed because the server runtime is not able to associate the operation's thread with any J2EE application component.  This condition can occur when the JNDI client using the "java:" name is not executed on the thread of a server application request.  Make sure that a J2EE application does not execute JNDI operations on "java:" names within static code blocks or in threads created by that J2EE application.  Such code does not necessarily run on the thread of a server application request and therefore is not supported by JNDI operations on "java:" names. [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name "comp/env/ibm.worklight.admin.lockTimeoutInMillis" not found in context "java:".]
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.throwExceptionIfDefaultJavaNS(javaURLContextImpl.java:522)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.throwConfigurationExceptionWithDefaultJavaNS(javaURLContextImpl.java:552)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.lookupExt(javaURLContextImpl.java:481)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookupExt(javaURLContextRoot.java:485)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:370)
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.common.util.ContextPropertyUtil.getContextProperty(ContextPropertyUtil.java:184)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.common.util.ContextPropertyUtil.getContextProperty(ContextPropertyUtil.java:164)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.common.util.ContextPropertyUtil.getContextProperty(ContextPropertyUtil.java:65)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.common.util.ContextPropertyUtil.getContextPropertyAsLong(ContextPropertyUtil.java:300)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.BaseCommitable.getLockTimeOutInMillis(BaseCommitable.java:415)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.CleanUnfinishedTransaction.cleanUnfinishedTransaction(CleanUnfinishedTransaction.java:94)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.BaseTransaction.internalRun(BaseTransaction.java:284)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.BaseTransaction$1.run(BaseTransaction.java:210)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:906)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:929)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:796)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name "comp/env/ibm.worklight.admin.lockTimeoutInMillis" not found in context "java:".
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookupInternal(NameSpace.java:1228)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookup(NameSpace.java:1141)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextImpl.lookupExt(UrlContextImpl.java:1436)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.lookupExt(javaURLContextImpl.java:477)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: Is this the full log? Do you have IIS in front of WAS? How are you deploying the .wlapp file?

Comment: If you try not-in this VM you're using, does it work? I suspect there is a nother artifact in play with some size limitation and not WAS.

Comment: Yes, there are some other logs I am not sure if they are related so i didn't post it. I installed an IIS when installing WAS. I go to work light console, select the .wlapp and click the button.

Comment: For your second reply, i don't understand what you what me to do, sorry. i can tell that VM is "clean", the first thing i did is to install IBM installation manager 1.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalled WAS 8.5.5.2 patch in IBM installation Manager to roll back to WAS 8.5.5.0 and restarted everything, then i can deploy adapters.

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft IIS there is an attribute that controls this filesize limit. This attribute is called `maxAllowedContentLength` and it can be found in the `<requestLimits>` element of the IIS configuration file. Its default value is 30 000 000 bytes.

You should increase it to a filesize tha will contain the wlapp's filesize.

Comment: oops..i couldn't find config file under "C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv"

Comment: The error messages in the log are related to a defect that is fixed in MobileFIrst Platform Foundation V6.3:  https://www-304.ibm.com/support/entdocview.wss?uid=swg1PI34203.  I am not sure how it connects to the file size (hopefully increasing this attribute will take care of that issue) but the message about the JNDI property, per se, can be disregarded unless you are actually trying to set that property.

Comment: Just to clarify, i selected IIS during WAS installation wizard, i have never started that web server's service. I am not setting any of these properties   but this is the exception thrown when deploying .wlapp.